# DataBinding reverses the order of my ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, data-binding, binding, observablecollection

I have the following custom observable collection (The code is taken in parts from Dean Chalk's blog http://www.deanchalk.me.uk/post/Thread-Safe-Dispatcher-Safe-Observable-Collection-for-WPF.aspx and slightly altered):

```
public class ThreadSaveObservableCollection <T> : IList<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged  {

    private IList<T> collection;
    private Dispatcher uiDispatcher;
    private ReaderWriterLock rwLock;

    public ThreadSaveObservableCollection () {

        collection = new List<T>();
        rwLock = new ReaderWriterLock();
        uiDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
    }

    public void Insert (int index, T item) {

        if (Thread.CurrentThread == uiDispatcher.Thread) {

            insert_(index, item);
        } else {

            uiDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<int, T>(insert_), DispatcherPriority.Normal, new object[] {index, item});
        }
    }

    private void insert_ (int index, T item) {

        rwLock.AcquireWriterLock(Timeout.Infinite);

        collection.Insert(index, item);
        CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item));

        rwLock.ReleaseWriterLock();
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator () {

        rwLock.AcquireReaderLock(Timeout.Infinite);

        IEnumerator<T> enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator();

        rwLock.ReleaseReaderLock();

        return enumerator;
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator () {

        rwLock.AcquireReaderLock(Timeout.Infinite);

        IEnumerator<T> enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator();

        rwLock.ReleaseReaderLock();

        return enumerator;
    }

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    ... // the remaining methods of the IList<> interface

}
```

Further I have a ViewModel which holds an instance of this class:

```
public class ViewModel {

    private ThreadSaveObservableCollection<string> Collection {get; set;}

    public ViewModel () {
        Collection = new ThreadSaveObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    public void Insert (string item) {

        Collection.Insert(0, item);
    }

}
```

I apply data binding in code-behind because I create the corresponding WPF control (an ordinary List control) with name "LogList" dynamically:

```
wpfContainer.LogList.ItemsSource = viewModel.Collection;
```

Everything works quite fine except the fact that the order of items in the wpf list control is reversed with respect to the items in the Collection object of the ViewModel.

With the statement Collection.Insert(0, intem) I expect to add the new item at the top of the list but what I get is the same result as I would use Collection.Add(item).

When I step into the code during runtime I can verify that the items inside my Collection are in the correct order but on the surface inside the wpf list control the order is altered i.e. reversed.

What am I making wrong ?

I guess the problem must be found somewhere around the data binding because it's the 'wire' that connects my ObservableCollection with the wpf control and it seems that a correct order is getting into the wire and an incorrect is leaving it.

Maybe it has something to do with the GetEnumerator() methods of the IList interface since the ItemSource property of the wpf control is awaiting an Enumerator ?

I have no clue and I am really stuck ...

Thank you in advance for any help ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to do this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653208.aspx

```
CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, new List<object>() { item }, 0));
```

I think that this event is the problem.

Comment: You are my absolute Hero !! What you've suggested worked perfectly !! You definitely saved my day !! :)

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say: Thank you very much *bowing* :)

Comment: @Marc happy to help :) Read Judah post also.

Answer (score 1):

Couple notes about your code:

- Naming: ThreadSafe, not ThreadSave
- Race conditions: you're acquiring a lock to call .GetEnumerator. Then releasing the lock, and returning that enumerator. That is not safe, and will throw an exception at runtime if the thread conditions are right. What you should do here is create a copy of the list while under lock, then return an enumerator to that copy.
- ReaderWriterLock has some known performance, scalability, and error-prone usage (e.g. re-entrance) concerns. Use [ReaderWriterLocksSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) instead.
- The whole idea here is to marshal all operations to the UI thread. If everything happens on the UI thread, there's no need for any locking at all.

Finally, rather than re-invent the wheel, I suggest using one of the existing [thread-safe ObservableCollections](http://www.deanchalk.me.uk/post/Thread-Safe-Dispatcher-Safe-Observable-Collection-for-WPF.aspx).

Comment: Your tips are very much appreciated. I have problems seeing the race condition with the GetEnumerator() method: When i lock the beginning of the method every other thread has to wait before entering, right ? So where is the race ? Regarding the use of the ReaderWriteLock class it was my first use and I have no experience with it - so thank you very much for that hint, I will dig into this topic :) Rgerading the marshalling: I am using this class in a multi-threaded application where the collection is altered by multiple threads other that the UI thread. ...

Comment: and regarding the wheel: I have used Dean Chalk's code and altered it a bit -> credits for that go of course directly to Dean Chalke, I am sorry that I forgot to mention that. I have updated my initial post above.

Comment: Marc, do other threads read this collection, or just write to it? Because the writing is already going through the Dispatcher, therefore, there's no reason to use locks unless other threads are also reading.

Comment: If you really do need locks, then your GetEnumerator is broken: yes, you're locking access to the enumerator, but the enumerator is operating on the same collection, which can be read and written to on different threads. Here's a scenario where it breaks: your list contains 1 item. Thread A calls .GetEnumerator. Thread A calls enumerator.MoveNext(), which returns true to indicate there are items available. Thread B removes the item. Thread A calls list.CurrentItem, expecting it to be non-null, but really it's null because the other thread removed it.

Comment: The threads are doing both reading and writing. In my application I have three observable collections. The threads are using one of them only to write into it but the other two are getting altered by the threads as well as read by them. So you mean when multiple threads only write into the collection the thread-synchronization is done by the UIDispatcher (at least in this scenario) ?

Comment: hmm .. I think I got your point but in your scenario how could Thread B remove an item from the collection since it uses the same lock as GetEnumerator() ? I am not sure if I fully understood that but the lock is the same in both methods GetEnumerator() and Remove(T item). So when Thread A enters GetEnumerator() it acquires the lock which means that Thread B can't acquire a writing lock when trying to enter the method Remove(T item) i.e. Trhead B is blocked until Thread A releases it's lock. Or am I thinking completely wrong ?

Comment: Thread A gets the enumerator, then *releases the lock*. Thread A calls enumerator.MoveNext *without any lock*. Thread B acquires the lock, removes the item. Thread A thinks the item will be there, but it's not.

Comment: Again, all this is moot if you don't really require locking. As your code stands, only the UI thread writes to the collection. (If another thread tries to write, you marshal that action to the UI thread to do the write.) So, **if the UI thread is the only thread that reads the collection, you don't need any locking at all**, vastly simplifying your code.

Comment: now I got you :) I will re-think that - for now I have removed the acquiring and releasing of the lock inside the GetEnumerator() methods AND I have renamed my class to **ExtendedObservableCollection** in order to avoid any further misleading designations and typos ;) ... Thank you very much for your help